# Google Maps Android API v2 supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Tags: android

I have an issue regarding OpenGL ES 2.0.  I am developing an android application with Google maps api v2. My logcat is returning an error "Google Maps Android API v2  supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above". My Phone's android version is 2.2.2. Is there anything i need to install at my device? please give me some advice regarding this issue. thanks.

at the manifest file

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: you should run your app on a device. requires google play services which may not be on device

Comment: Yes. Ive already done that but still I'm getting an error from my logcat.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: download and install: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.hardwareinfo (or other program which can show you your device specs) then check if your phone supports opengl es 2.0 ... android version is not directly conected with opengl version ... so you can have API 8 android without opengl es 2.0 support

Comment: Also try adding hardware acceleration to your app

Comment: I installed the Android Hardware Info. The device specs are the ff: Phone's api level is 8 and OpenGL 1.X (Android PixelFlinger 1.3) - OpenGL ES-CM 1.0. How can I update the opengl? is it possible to update the opengl?

Comment: "How can I update the opengl?" -- ask your device manufacturer if they have a firmware update. Or, install a ROM mod for your device. Or, buy a new device.